# Listview does not auto update itself

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, adapter

each time my activty receives a message (from some TCP listening thread), it does

```
mLstAdpChatScreen.add(line);
updateUI();



private void updateUI()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            mLstAdpChatScreen.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mLstAdpChatScreen.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            mLstVwChatScreen.requestLayout();
            mLstVwChatScreen.invalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

While this approach works on most of my listviews and they do get updated, it does not for a certain listview. I must be missing something :-?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work for most of the cases however I got the same problem when trying to update listview from database. I called  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` too, but listview didn't update at all although I could confirmed the data was changed, and the `ArrayList`'s size increased.

In the end, I implemented a method inside my custom `Adapter` extending from `BaseAdapter` just to call `notifyDataSetChanged` there, like

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public void updateData(){
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Then in `Activity`, I just call `adapter.updateData()`. And this worked for me. Very weird.

Comment: actually that did the trick - after I have fixed some other issues